# Momentjs: Convertir hora local a Epoch

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy usando momentjs para convertir horas, nesesito convertir una hora a epoch con el siguiente formato

```
   // hora epoch: 1582301681.084594
```

uso el siguiente codigo para tratar de encontrar la solución

```
var epoch1 = moment('2020-02-01T15:00:00', "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss").valueOf();
console.log(epoch1);
// resultado: 1582327901000
```

pero no logro hacer que el formato vaya con punto decimal

Comment: Cuantas cifras significativas necesitas?

Comment: en el formato deseado se muestra 6 y realmente no se que significa los números despues del punto.

Comment: Yo no he usado esa librería (moment.js) pero por el valor que muestras imagino que sea un timestamp (en este momento en segundos es 1582308905) los tres ceros pueden ser para medir milisegundos. De modo que debes dividir por 1000 y tomar la parte entera.